# How to use wav2letter in 2021

Tags: linux, docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, speech-recognition

I've been trying to use Facebook's wav2letter speech recognition model for **inference only**, and found that installing it is very difficult. They've released two newer models, wav2letter++ and wav2vec, which adds a bit to the confusion. It appears that [this](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter) repo is for wav2letter++, and [this](https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight) repo is for pure wav2letter.

There are even more problems that make this process difficult, such as the fact that it appears they restructured the repo some time ago and therefore many GitHub wiki links are correspondingly broken and files not in expected places.

**Does anyone know how to use wav2letter in 2021? My end game is to use it for transcriptions of audio files and possible real-time transcription in Python.**

I'll summarize some of what I've tried to get it to work below if it is relevant/for those interested:

## What I've Tried

This goes temporally, so I don't recall a lot of the earlier errors/problems:

### Using Win11

- Couldn't get Flashlight, a dependency, to install
- Tried compiling binary inference model myself but didn't have all the header files

### Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with x86_64 ISA on VMware Player

#### Using pre-built Docker images as laid out [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Building-Running-with-Docker#using-pre-built-docker-images)

1. Went well until I tried the `git remote set-url https://github.com/facebookresearch/wav2letter.git` in the "for Inferences pipeline" above the [this](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Building-Running-with-Docker#build-images-by-yourself) header, I got a usage error for `set-url` because two arguments were expected.
2. From here, I tried doing `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/facebookresearch/wav2letter.git` and moving forward, eventually reaching the error:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

3. I tried to build with cmake anyway, which was an apparent success.
4. Then from the `build` folder, I tried following the **Simple Streaming ASR Example** from [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Inference-Run-Examples#simple-streaming-asr-example). From here, I got this error:

```
cat: /root/audio/LibriSpeech/dev-clean/777/126732/777-126732-0070.flac.wav: No such file or directory
Started features model file loading ... 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to open feature file=/root/model/feature_extractor.bin for reading
Aborted (core dumped)
```

From here, I shut down and deleted the container

#### Simple Streaming ASR Example using Docker as laid out [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Inference-Run-Examples#quickly-run-streaming-asr-examples-using-docker)

Here I ran the listed command and received this error:

```
cat: /root/host/audio/LibriSpeech/dev-clean/777/126732/777-126732-0070.flac.wav: No such file or directory
Started features model file loading ... 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to open feature file=/root/host/model/feature_extractor.bin for reading
Aborted (core dumped)
```

#### Building the Docker image myself as seen [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Building-Running-with-Docker#trainingdecoding-inside-container)

Here, cloning went fine, but after that I got this error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ryan/wav2letter/Dockerfile-Inference: no such file or directory
```

Then I ran `sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt` from the `wav2letter` directory and got this error:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ryan/wav2letter/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ryan/wav2letter/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

#### Not using Docker

### Download and build wav2letter-inference as seen [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Inference-Run-Examples#download-and-build-wav2letter-inference)

This led to needing MKL and [Flashlight](https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight). I could not get Flashlight to install. I tried

1. [as library](https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight#installing-flashlight-with-vcpkg) with vcpkg
2. [from source](https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight#from-source-build-with-vcpkg) with vcpkg
3. [building from source](https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight#building-from-source) which lead to problems downloading Flashlight.

### Lastly, I tried following [this](https://medium.com/@shaheenkader/how-to-install-wav2letter-dc94c3b74e97) tutorial

Eventually running into an error, I believe installing Flashlight